# Why can't Goku battle in space while the previous Sayans can?

Tags: dragon-ball

About the saiyans who battled Freeza, they can battle in space but I think Goku is unable to because when an explosion is about to happen in Planet Nemic, Kayosama said that Goku is at a disadvantage because Goku will not survive in space and Freeza would. Again, the flash-back battle between the Saiyans revolution (when Goku escaped), they were all in space, no gravity, no air pressure or whatever, Planet Vegeta in the background...

Also when Goku is chasing Robo Freeza and his dad, he can't Go out of the Pod because he isn't at Earth's atmosphere yet.

Comment: I think you need to make what your question is more obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a problem with the animation. The reality is that the scene you refer to with planet Vegeta in the background doesn't take place in space. It takes place in the high atmosphere of the planet. Low oxygen content, but not none. And the Saiyans aren't there for very long. (and weren't planning to be) Goku would have needed to spend hours, days, or weeks in the vacuum of space.

Consider this: if they could survive is space, surly some of them fled out as Freeza attacked. Those few could have therefore survived.

Additionally, during the Garlic Junior saga, Vegeta is shown to travel between a planet and its moon. The background shows a strange blue glow, which one can take to mean that the moon and planet share an atmosphere. (I won't comment on the realism of that.)

Comment: There was a character named Garlic?

Comment: i think so yes. http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Garlic

Comment: @OghmaOsiris Garlic Jr. This is only the beginning of the silliness that is DB names. [Piccolo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piccolo_%28Dragon_Ball%29) first appeared with characters [Drum](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Drum), Cymbal, Tambourine and Piano. The Saiyans are all words for veggies: Vegeta, Raditz, Nappa, Kakarot, Broly. There is no end to it.

Comment: Whomever upvoted this answer just put my power level over 9000!!!!